# Получить объект с другого сайта

Tags: javascript

Пишу небольшого бота для чата твича (без сервера) и хочу добавить фановую функцию случайного слова.

Т.к. массив с ~1000 слов займет много места, собираюсь воспользоваться сайтом http://sluchajnoe.ru/slovo.php

Как мне получить от него слово?
Весь скрипт просто внедряю на страницу твича через консоль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массив с 1000 слов не займет много места. Давайте посчитаем.

Предположим, что вы кодируете текст UTF-8 и слова у вас русские.

Для кодирования одной буквы из кириллицы требуется 2 байта, предположим, что средняя длина слова у вас 10 символов, следовательно на одно слово Вам требуется 20 байт. На массив из 1000 слов Вам **примерно** потребуется 20000 байт или 19.5 КБ.

Вы не сможете сделать запрос на другой ресурс напрямую через AJAX и спарсить значение слова с этого ресурса, политика браузеров запрещает **напрямую** делать любые запросы на сторонние ресурсы. Можно попробовать найти ресурс, который поддерживает и позволяет это делать через JSONP или CORS, но Вам видимо будет проще иметь копию подобной базы, т.к. подобных ресурсов я не нашел c данными разрешениями.

Логичнее, чтобы серверный скрипт был на стороне сервера и выдавал случайное слово, а вот серверный скрипт может подключаться куда угодно и получать данные откуда угодно, но это Вам не подходит, у Вас же просто внедрение на страницу только JS, без возможности серверной части на этом же домене.

Comment: Спасибо, а как это сделать, допустим, на Node.js? Я работал с запросами, когда был полный доступ и к серверу, и к сайту, а как это сделать здесь, пока не пойму :/

Comment: @Виталий Nodejs тот же самый backend, как PHP или Java, а не клиентская часть, пишите на нем метод, на который можно обращаться, который возвращает случайное слово, и дергаете метод сервера на этом же домене, на котором подключен скрипт, через клиентский javascript.